# Perform click action, process current page and go back StaleElementReference selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Currently having quite the issue with selenium.

I am trying to get all the links on a page, click each, obtain the data from the page and go back. Even when using the StaleElementReference exception handler, it will completely break the loop,despite using `driver.back()` as is advised.

The code is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from datetime import datetime
from pymongo import MongoClient
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

options = Options()
options.page_load_strategy = 'none'
# options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
url = "https://www.depop.com/purevintage_clothing/"
# driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

for link in links:
  linkClass = link.get_attribute("class")
  try:
      if str(linkClass[:19]) == "styles__ProductCard":
         
        action = ActionChains(driver)
        action.move_to_element(link)
        action.click().perform()

        product = doSomethingFunction()

        if product != None:
           insertIntoDatabase(product)

        driver.back()

  except StaleElementReferenceException as e:
       print(e)
       driver.back()
```

I am aware indentation is a bit dodgy here, wrote this out manually as the rest of the processing code such as insertIntoDatabase I'm not sure is relevant here (please let me know if you need all of it)

Whenever I do this I end up with the error exception in a loop despite the `driver.back()` I'm sure the answer is staring me in the face and I'm a bit too dense to see it, but any help is appreciated here

Comment: When you execute `action.click().perform()`, that will presumably take you to a new page. How do you know when you have arrived at the new page? It's when `link` has become stale. So it is on a raised `StaleElementReferenceException` that you want to invoke `product = doSomethingFunction()`. and then do a `driver.back()` on return. How do you know `link` is stale? Enter into a loop that repeatedly executes `link.find_elements_by_id('some_arbitary_value')` until you get an exception (you can add `time.sleep(.1)` between calls, if you want). (more...)

Comment: Alternatively, there is no need to test for staleness of the old page if the first thing `doSomethingFunction()` does is test for the presence of a known element on the new page. This would really be the preferred way to proceed.

Comment: By the way, this is not a Minimal Reproducible Example since you do not show how `links` is computed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you go back to the main page you need to get links because they are not present in the DOM anymore since you changed page; so you should do as follows:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(path_to_elements)
for i in range(len(links)):
    link = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(path_to_elements)[i]
    linkClass = link.get_attribute("class")

    if str(linkClass[:19]) == "styles__ProductCard":
        action = ActionChains(driver)
        action.move_to_element(link)
        action.click().perform()

        product = doSomethingFunction()

        if product != None:
            insertIntoDatabase(product)

        driver.back()
```